# Python-3 y manejo de archivos externos txt

Tags: python-3.x, txt

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

Escriba un programa que lea los dni contenidos en un fichero y escriba los nif correspondientes en otro fichero. Puede haber más de un dni por lineal.

Consideraremos que un número es un dni correcto si es positivo y tiene 8 dígitos. Los nombres de los dos ficheros se introducirán por teclado.
Hasta ahora yo he hecho esto:

```
fichero_a=open('dni5_7.txt','r')
letra='TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE'
count=0
lista=[]
for numero in fichero_a:
    lista.append(numero)

print lista
```

Dando como resultado esto:

```
['29042806 29237340 29345675\n', '41894345\n', '2934556 2934589\n', '41789456\n']
```

Busco la lista ya que es más fácil manipularlas, quiero hacer que cada número sea un elemento después ya discriminaría los números menores de 8 y haría la asignación de letra con el operador de resto
Si me pueden echar una mano se lo agradecería.
Saludos

Comment: Puede resultarte más sencillo leer el fichero completo en una sola cadena y hacer `split()` sobre ella, ya que esa función te divide tanto por líneas como por elementos separados con espacios. Así cada elemento de la lista resultante sería ya un solo número. O sea: `todo = fichero_a.read()` y luego `lista = todo.split()`

Comment: No entiendo muy bien su respuesta, lo he intentado(creo) y sólo aparece el último elemento

Comment: Intenta estas cuatro líneas: `fichero_a=open('dni5_7.txt','r')`; `todo=fichero_a.read()`; `lista=todo.split()`; `print(lista)` Debería mostrar una lista en la que cada elemento es un DNI (guardado como cadena).

Comment: Cierto muchas gracias, ¿pero está guardado como cadena? ¿y no como número?

Comment: Sí, cada elemento de esa lista es una cadena, pues el resultado de leer del archivo son cadenas. Puedes convertir cada una en número si lo necesitas con algo como: `numeros = [ int(num) for num in lista]`. Si no conoces esta sintaxis (se llama comprensión de listas) puedes usar un bucle for "normal" para iterar por la lista de cadenas e ir creando otra lista de números.

Comment: Un detalle. Veo que has usado la etiqueta python-3.x pero sin embargo tu código contiene un `print` sin paréntesis, que sólo es válido en Python2. Aclara bien qué versión de python usas.

Comment: Bueno, yo sólo quiero contar los elementos uno a uno para que tengan 8 caracteres, ver que sean positivos y después asignarle la letra, con lo cual da igual si son cadenas o números, pero ahora no lo consigo, estoy bastante espeso, acabo de salir de una ruptura y no tengo la mente clara

Comment: Yo pensaba que usaba la 3, pero por lo que acabas de decir, parece que no

Comment: ¿Qué es un DNI? ¿Qué es un NIF?

Comment: Documento de identidad, como 29234567Q

Answer (score 0):

Para darte un código de partida por el que puedas continuar, te mostraré cómo obtener del fichero la lista de números por la que luego podrías iterar para añadirles la letra y así formar el DNI.

Se trata simplemente, como te decía en los comentarios, de leer el fichero de una sola vez (todas las líneas juntas a una sola cadena) y después partir esa cadena con la operación `.split()`. Esto es interesante en este caso particular porque el enunciado dice que una línea puede tener uno o varios números separados por espacios. El operador `split()` separa en elementos independientes todo lo que esté separado por espacios o por retornos de carro, así que te funciona para separar por líneas y para separar por espacios dentro de las líneas todo a la vez.

```py
fichero = open('dni5_7.txt','r')
contenido = fichero.read()         # Lee todo el fichero completo
fichero.close()

dnis = contenido.split()
```

El resultado en `dnis` debería ser algo como:

```
['29042806`,  `29237340`,  `29345675', '41894345', '2934556`,  `2934589', '41789456']
```

Observa que cada elemento de esa lista es una cadena que contiene ya el número que buscabas y no hay ningún `\n` en ellos. Sólo tienes que iterar por los elementos de esa lista para añadirles la letra, con un esquema como este:

```
nifs = []
for numero in dnis:
   # 1. Verificar que el número es correcto
   # Por ejemplo len(numero) te dice cuantas cifras tiene
   # numero.isdigit() te devuelve True si todos los caracteres del numero son cifras
   #  o False si no, lo que también puede ser útil para validar que sea correcto

   # 2. Calcular la letra que correspondería a ese DNI, con el algoritmo que sea
   letra = ...

   # 3. Añadir la letra y meterlo en la lista de NIFs
   nifs.append(numero + letra)
```