# fichero txt y letra del DNI

Tags: python, txt

llevo unos días con un programa en el que tengo que hacer lo siguiente
Escriba un programa que lea los dni contenidos en un fichero y escriba los nif correspondientes en otro fichero. Puede haber más de un dni por línea. Consideraremos que un número es un dni correcto si es positivo y tiene 8 dígitos. Los nombres de los dos ficheros se introducirán por teclado.

```
fichero_a=open('dni5_7.txt','r')
letra='TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE'
todo=fichero_a.read()
lista_dni=todo.split()

for i in (lista_dni):
    if (len(lista_dni[i]))==8 and lista_dni[i]>0:
        print lista_dni[i],letra[i%23]
```

me da error, en concreto este

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Ya he pedido ayuda varias veces pero no consigo cerrar el programa, si alguien me echa una mano se lo agradecería,saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Python-3 y manejo de archivos externos txt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394882/python-3-y-manejo-de-archivos-externos-txt)

Comment: Es una pésima práctica el escribir la misma pregunta. Tú mismo dices que has pedido ayuda antes, en la pregunta que te marcan como duplicado hay numerosos comentarios pidiendo aclaraciones... posiblemente tu pregunta carece de detalles que impiden ayudarte?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te dice es que el índice de la lista debe ser un entero, no una cadena de texto, cuando haces el primer loop lo que esta sobteniendo es texto

lista_dni =["66222333","22444666"]

```
for i in lista_dni:
print(i)

/66222333

/22444666
```

y cuando entras a la condicion... lista_dni[i] no te da un resultado válido. Por que "i" no es una variable válida.

```
for i in lista_dni:
        print(lista_dni[i])

"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File 

 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

[Program finished]

""""
```

Deberías hacer primero un loop que tw diga la cantidad de items que hay en tu lista...

```
dni_qty = len(lista_dni)
print(dni_qty)
/ 2
```

Y usar eso en el loop

```
for i in range(dni_qty):
    print(lista_dni[i])

/ 66222333

/ 22444666
```

Espero que te sirva . Salu3

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió